# Solr max results for particular field type

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 4.10.3.

I have various fields in schema. e.g id,title,content,type etc. I have docs scenario such that many docs have same type value.

```
id  |  title  |  content  |   type

1   |   pro   |     My    |   abc
2   |   ver   |    name   |   ht
3   |   art   |     is    |   abc
```

and so on.

When I query Solr, I want total 10 results(as default) but in them only maximum two of `type:abc`. Rest of the 8 results can be of any type except `abc` and can be more of one type.

Is there any possible solution.?

Comment: Take a look to [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) and [this one](http://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-result-grouping-field-collapsing-improvements/)

Comment: I don't want their grouping but simply indivdual results

Answer (score 1):

Make two queries, once with `rows=2 and type:abc`, and second time with `rows=8 and -type:abc`. Rest of the query can be identical. Then combine the results before you show them to users.

EDIT: After some research on what comes next in Solr features, I believe that combining the results will become possible once the streaming expressions are part of Solr (maybe in 5.2). See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7377

Comment: Is there a way that I can combine two different queries in one line ?

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible without some extensive work, such as writing your own search handler plugin. Probably not something you want to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Solr 5.2 you can accomplish this using the Streaming Expressions (and the Streaming API under the covers). The expression would be

```
top(n=10,
    merge(
      top(n=2, 
          search(fl="id, title, content, type", q="type:abc", sort="title asc")
      ),
      search(fl="id, title, content, type", q="-type:abc", sort="title asc")
      on="title asc"
    )
)
```

What's going on here is that first you're finding at most two documents of type "abc", then you are finding all documents that are not of type "abc". Notice that both of these are sorted by "title asc" (it's important that they be sorted by the same field(s)). Then we merge these two streams on the field "title" in ascending order. What this does is, using the title field, pick the first document from one of the streams, then it picks the second document, then the third, and so on. By merging "on title" what we're doing is using the title field to decide which document comes first in the merged stream. The outer top will ensure that only 10 documents are returned. Because we limited the "type:abc" stream to have at most 2 documents the final merged stream will have at most 2 "type:abc" documents.

Obviously you can change the sort criteria to whatever is best for you but it is critical with a merge that the incoming streams are sorted in the same order. And in fact, the Streaming API will validate that for you and reject the expression if that is not the case.